# How to calibrate an ammeter and voltmeter?

Tags: current, voltage

How can I calibrate  an ammeter and a voltmeter.

[image]

I just want to know about it. Because it might be helpful and I think it is a vital thing to know. So how can I do this?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Then can this transfer ?

Comment: After migrating it to this site this became a trivial question. Shouldn't we vote for close?

Answer (score 2):

Most analogue devices, shown on your picture, have a calibration screw which makes it quite easy. These screws are given on the right-bottom side of devices. Using them you can calibrate the output by manually turning the indicator when reference current/voltage is supplied. Do this for maximal value (in this case 15 Amps or 500 Volts). You should use the reference source, capable to provide the exact current/voltage with desired accuracy.

There are no such possibilities in most digital meters avalilable on the market (*), so current/voltage dividers methods are used.

*Note that you need to have precise equipment for this, as currents flowing through a voltmeter are microampers, and voltage drops on ammeters are at most milivolts in typical solutions.*

For an ammeter you should measure its internal resistance (or impedance if it is AC ammeter). Then you add in parallel a resistance (impedance) so that for desired current (in the picture `15 A`) flowing through both ammeter and the resistance will be exact.

Controlling the resistance you add in parallel you can lower the current flowing through the ammeter, so you do it when the ammeter shows higher current than it really is. There is no possibility to calibrate it when it shows too few (you can't increase the current flowing through the ammeter).

This is also valid when you want to scale your ammeter (eg. showing 5 Amps when there really is 20 A).

The background of this is that (\$Rm\$ - ammeter resistance, \$Ra\$ - resistance added) in parallel connection the equivalent resistance is

$$ \frac{1}{R} = \frac 1 {Rm} + \frac 1 {Ra} $$

$$R = \frac {Rm Ra}{Rm+Ra}$$

For current \$I\$ the voltage drop caused on the system is

$$U = I R = I \frac {Rm Ra}{Rm+Ra}$$

The current flowing through the ammeter is

$$Im = \frac U {Rm} = \frac {I \frac {Rm Ra}{Rm+Ra}} {Rm}  =  \frac {I {Ra}} {Rm + Ra}$$

So changing the \$Ra\$ you can change the current flowing through the meter. For example, if \$Ra = Rm\$ you have half of the current flowing through the ammeter.

Doing this, keep in mind that both \$Ra\$ and \$Rm\$ are small (miliOhms). This cause influence of such elements as wires, connections etc., and temperature factor can have an impact.

This is analogous for a voltmeter, however here you add a resistance in series, to lower the voltage.

There is also no possibility to increase the measured voltage by connecting in series (you need negative resistance).

[Further reading](http://create-and-make.com/scaling-a-voltmeter-an-ammeter/) about dividers

---

(*) some more expensive devices allow scaling by multiplying the output by some factor you type, eg. `1.0001`, so this is equivalent to the mentioned screw.

Answer (score 2):

Proper calibration (as opposed to some ad hoc method using a reference piece of equipment that may also need calibrating) is not cheap and, for the types of meters shown in the question, it is probably (or usually) cheaper to buy new parts. But, when you buy the new parts, ensure they are calibrated and have some form of calibration certificate.

Further thoughts: -

- Equipment that does not have a data sheet that tells you the method of calibration is probably not worth considering as an in-house standard.
- Equipment that does not specify a calibration interval is probably not worth considering as an in-house standard.
- Equipment that does not tell you the environmental operating conditions not worth considering as an in-house standard.

You also have to decide on the "standard" of calibration you want to achieve. This is all about attaining a degree of accuracy and any testing (by comparison with a reference) requires the reference instrument is calibrated and has a known accuracy. For instance, if your aim is to produce a calibration certificate for something to be shipped to a customer then you will likely need to list all the equipment used and the methods.

Informal testing for in-house purposes is one thing but, calibration is another and the latter needs to be treated with much more respect. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration) says this about calibration: -

> The formal definition of calibration by the International Bureau of
>   Weights and Measures is the following: "Operation that, under
>   specified conditions, in a first step, establishes a relation between
>   the quantity values with measurement uncertainties provided by
>   measurement standards and corresponding indications with associated
>   measurement uncertainties (of the calibrated instrument or secondary
>   standard) and, in a second step, uses this information to establish a
>   relation for obtaining a measurement result from an indication.

So, if you want to calibrate a voltmeter or ammeter, check with the supplier's information about exactly what needs to be done to achieve this.